# heroku toolbelt installation - Missing Instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, setup-deployment, heroku-toolbelt

I downloaded the windows version of heroku toolbelt from here https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

I chose my folder as

C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku

which is NOT where my rails app directories are.

Now, according to the heroku homepage guide, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart#step-2-install-the-heroku-toolbelt

it says 
"Step 3: Login

After installing the Toolbelt, you’ll have access to the heroku command from your command shell. Authenticate using the email address and password you used when creating your Heroku account:"

Where do i go to do this? I don't see an executable command terminal file in any of the folders of where Heroku installed itself.

My heroku folder contains these directories and files
bin
data
lib
ruby-1.9.2
vendor
unins000.dat
unins000.exe
unins000.msg

I try to execute commands on my windows command prompt, but that doesn't work either. I also used railsinstaller to install rails, ruby, git, etc., so i tried to run heroku commands from the Git Bash and that does not work either.

All of the instructions i read online, including the Github page for heroku toolbelt omits this crucial information. https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb They will all tell you what commands to type, but don't tell you where to go or which command terminal to open from which folder after downloading.

Now, from my Git bash terminal, which I got from using railsinstaller, I can install the heroku gem, foreman gem, but the heroku gem is deprecated. Toolbelt is what I should be using, and here I am without a critical piece of information.

Does no one else have any problems installing heroku toolbelt and getting it to function? I'm kind of surprised that the omitted information hasn't seemed to spark other heroku toolbelt installation questions yet. Hopefully this question will help other first-timers as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: look into the **bin/** folder, and see that files that there are.

Comment: I actually opened the heroku.bat file, but it instantly closes on me.

maybe i should restart computer. I certainly tried reinstalling.

Comment: Try to add the full path to heroku's `bin/` folder into your account's path variable at the beginning. Then restart shell, and try to call the `heroku` command again

Answer (score 1):

You need to be logged in as an administrator for the installation to work. If you weren't try it again with that privilege.

After installing the toolbelt, the system path should include the installation folder's bin. On my 64-bit Win 7 box its':

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin
```

There should also be a system level variable called `HerokuPath`.

So if you start a *new* CMD shell, say `path` and what appears should include the path above (or similar for your machine).

Also say `set HerokuPath` and the path should appear here.

Then the `heroku` command should run with no problems, and you can follow the instructions.

If you still have problems, it's likely that one of the embedded installations in the toolbelt is in conflict with another version of the same already on your system.  Try running a shell that has a minimal path plus the `HerokuPath` contents.  The most likely culprit is another Ruby installation.  The `heroku` command is a Ruby script in disguise.

Comment: Do you mean administrator for windows? my account is. I also tried explicitly right clicking "run as administrator", and still no luck.

set HerokuPath gave me this error. Environment variable HerokuPath not defined. does this mean heroku didn't install properly?

Comment: "The most likely culprit is another Ruby installation."

I'm not quite sure what you mean by this. What are the steps to doing this?

Is the normal heroku gem i installed using Git Bash conflicting, or the previous installation of heroku toolbelt?

Comment: I'm not able to get it running yet, but all your information was very enlightening.

Comment: In your question, add the output of the `path` command.  However if `HerokuPath` is not set, something is definitely wrong with your shell.  How are you starting the shell, and is it `CMD` or something else?

Comment: I am using CMD when i run "path" I am not sure how to get the output of path, other than by typing. I confirmed there was no heroku path in that list visually, and by running a right click search.

Comment: I set aside heroku toolbelt for now (because i couldn't get anywhere with it), and am currently experimenting with using the deprecated heroku gem from my Git Bash. The gem still allows me to create apps on heroku, although I have yet to get it to host, accept ssh keys, and work, when i type "heroku open". Should I stop playing with the deprecated heroku gem, or does it actually still work?